# Play Local Notification sound twice

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I'm using UILocalNotification in my app. My doubt, Is't possible to play the UiLocalNotification sound two time continually. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please drop your ideas here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Unfortunately you cant play the sound repeatedly. One possible solution for this problem is you can use custom sound for the UILocalNotification. So make a file that sounds two times and make it as your notification's sound. One important thing is you cant add a file of more than 30 seconds duration

Comment: Just be aware that the sound can not play for longer the 30 seconds. you should read [Preparing Custom Alert Sounds](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6).

Comment: TanQ @manujmv . But, My requirement is , the sound should play based on the no of rows available in tableview. (ie) if my table view contains 2 row means it should play 2 times, same like 3 row means 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

use @property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *soundName in Local notification you can play a sound file of your choice using this..